# How to share common variable between two functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can `func1` share variable `a` with `func2` without global keyword in python?

```
def func1():
    a= 5
    print(a)

def func2():        
    print(a)

func1()
func2()
```

Comment: Use return values and arguments in your functions, or a class.

Comment: No, i want func1 to update value of  variable, and same variable must be allowed in func2

Comment: Variables that are defined in a function are lost as soon as the function has returned. They don't have a state over multiple executions. Such a statefule execution can be done with classes.

Comment: Why don't use a class and use `a` as a class attribute, that is one of the advantages of OOP. Check my answer below on how to do that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just define both functions in a class, and make `a` as an attribute.

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def func1(self):
        self.a= 5
        print(self.a)

    def func2(self):
        print(self.a)


obj = A(4)
obj.func2()
obj.func1()
```

The output will be.

```
4
5
```

Comment: I'm voting this one because is what the OP **need**.  But shouldn't be the case for the example.

Comment: Thanks @Netwave Not sure when you say `shouldn't be the case for the example`

Comment: I mean that just because a variable need to be shared it doesn't mean you have to wrap everything in a class.

Comment: I think it is slightly better than from passing the variables around, but not by much!

Comment: Would using a global variable be a better or worse approach

Comment: Because if you change global in one function, it changes in all other functions!

Answer (score 3):

Just return the variable from your first funtion and capture it in the second:

```
def func1():
    a= 5
    print(a)
    return a
def func2(a):        
    print(a)

a = func1()
func2(a)
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/DarksalmonLastDirectory)

If what you want is to update a variable within your pyqt app you can use [@Devesh answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55863826/1695172)

Comment: this is sample question, right now iam working with pyqt button, so returning value is giving me error

Answer (score -1):

Define `a` outside the function.

```
a = 5

def func1():
    print(a)

def func2():        
    print(a)

func1()
func2()
```

Output:

```
5                                                                                                                                     
5
```

Remember

- not best practice
- does only work for read access to a

Comment: The moment you want to change a from within the function, you have to use "global". He's asking how to avoid doing it this way, imo.

Comment: You should make clear that this is (a) not best practice and (b) does only work for read access to `a`.